# Upgrade MySQL to v5.7+

Tags: upgrade, mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a message in my installation as follows: "To prepare for CiviCRM v5.34+, please upgrade MySQL. The recommended version will be MySQL v5.7+ or MariaDB v10.1+."

My site is hosted on Siteground. They said I can't upgrade to MySql 5.7+ at the moment, but will be able to do so soon. I currently have this version of MySql: Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3

What will happen if Civi upgrades to 5.34+ before I can upgrade to MySQL 5.7+.

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is from 2015, so it's disappointing that a major host doesn't offer it.  However, you're not forced to upgrade past CiviCRM 5.33 until you're able to.

Comment: I just raised this with Siteground today and got a 'No plans to upgrade to 5.7 this year' which is very disappointing, to say the least.  I guess we'll be leaving Siteground for my clients, especially in view of Search Kit coming in Civi.

Answer (score 1):

5.34 is 6 months from now. So it depends what siteground means by "soon" :)

Comment: Thanks. They said that soon would mean this year.